How can I generate a MakeFile for an OMNeT++ simulation?
I am a new OMNeT++ user (6.0.3) running inet 4.5. I am trying out the first part of the INET Tutorial for setting up two wireless hosts communicating with each other.
I am having an issue with the makefile generation. It keeps giving me this error:

src/Makefile does not exist. Please use "make makefiles" to generate it.

How do I generate the required makefiles because the makefile is already in the Project File tree with the following code:
all: checkmakefiles
    cd src && $(MAKE)

clean: checkmakefiles
    cd src && $(MAKE) clean

cleanall: checkmakefiles
    cd src && $(MAKE) MODE=release clean
    cd src && $(MAKE) MODE=debug clean
    rm -f src/Makefile

makefiles:
    cd src && opp_makemake -f --deep

checkmakefiles:
    @if [ ! -f src/Makefile ]; then \
    echo; \
    echo '======================================================================='; \
    echo 'src/Makefile does not exist. Please use "make makefiles" to generate it!'; \
    echo '======================================================================='; \
    echo; \
    exit 1; \
    fi

Please what am I missing?

OMNeT++ has two different Makefiles. One Makefile in the project root.
As you can see in your posted Makefile it contains the command makefiles: cd src && opp_makemake -f --deep this command creates a new Makefile in the src/ folder.
The error message tells you exactly what you need to do though:

Please use "make makefiles" to generate it

Simply open a terminal/console, enter make makefiles and run the command.
This will then generate the Makefile in the src/ folder.

Please thank you @ich5003
I will implement your answer and get back to you.
I am so grateful
